# Adjunction Formula (on surfaces)

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Assume that $X$ is a smooth, complex surface and $D\subset X$ a smooth curve. I am reading a book where the equality

$K_X\cdot D + D^2 + \chi(D,\mathcal{O}_D) = 0$

is being referred to as the *Adjunction Formula*. The latter I know as $K_D=(K_X+D)|_D$, and I do not understand how the above follows. A reference is given, but said reference also translates to the version I know, and I cannot seem to prove that it implies the above.

Comment: From the formula you know one obtains $\deg K_D= K_X D +D^2$, hence $K_XD+D^2 - \deg K_D=0$. But $\deg K_D=2g(D)-2=-2\chi(D, \mathcal{O}_D$, so we have $K_X\cdot D + D^2 + 2\chi(D,\mathcal{O}_D) = 0$. Are you sure that there is no 2 multiplying $\chi$?

Comment: Indeed, also see Proposition 1.5 in Chapter V of Hartshorne.

Comment: The formula is correct if you replace $\chi(D,{\mathcal )}_D)$ by the topological Euler characteristic. Maybe that's what the book's author means.


Comment: @rita: That _might_ just be possible, the notation is ambiguous. Thanks everybody, I will check if it's a missing factor of 2 or the topological Euler characteristic, that shouldn't be too hard to figure out.

Comment: it's not onlly the factor of 2, it's also  the sign